# Determinate coordinates based on three different group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df which looks like this :

```
Dat1 = read.table(text=" Plot   Ori  Treatment Dist Spot
9  W PT 10 LE1  
8  S PT 9 LE1
7  W PT 5 LE1
6  S PT 4.5 LE1
5  C PT 0 LE1
4  N PT 4.5 LE1
3  E PT 5 LE1
2  N PT 9  LE1
1  E PT 10 LE1
11 W PT 10 LE2 
12 S PT 9 LE2 
13 W PT 5 LE2 
14 S PT 4.5 LE2 
15 C PT 0 LE2 
16 N PT 4.5 LE2 
17 E PT 5 LE2 
18 N PT 9 LE2 
19 E PT 10 LE2 ", header=TRUE)
```

I have to put x and y coordinates on each plot based on multiple factors:
First, Keep both `LE1` and `LE2` plots separate.
Then, as you see, all even numbers are labelled on the `Ori` column: `N` if they are smaller than the center plot (Labelled `C`) and `S` if they bigger. It is the same for the odd numbers labelled `E` (if smaller) `W` (if bigger).

I'd like the final df to look like this one :

```
Finale = read.table(text=" Plot Ori Treatment Dist Spot  x y
9  W PT 10 LE1 -4 0 
8  S PT 9 LE1 0 -4
7  W PT 5 LE1 -2 0
6  S PT 4.5 LE1 0 -2
5  C PT 0  LE1 0  0
4  N PT 4.5  LE1 0  2
3  E PT 5  LE1 2  0
2  N PT 9  LE1 0  4
1  E PT 10  LE1 4  0
11  W PT 10 LE2 -4 0 
12 S PT 9 LE2 0 -4
13  W PT 5 LE2 -2 0
14  S PT 4.5 LE2 0 -2
15  C PT 0  LE2 0  0
16  N PT 4.5 LE2 0  2
17  E PT 5 LE2 2  0
18  N PT 9 LE2 0  4
19  E PT 10 LE2 4  0", header=TRUE)
```

As you can see, both `N` and `E` plot have positive coordinates and both `S` and `W` have negative one. The bigger the number in `Dist` column is, the farther is the plot from the center (Ex: center = Plot 5 for LE1), so the farther it is on the `x` or `y` axis.

I hope I made myself clear enough, thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. `all even numbers are labelled on the Ori column` which numbers are you referring to as even number? `N if they are smaller than the center plot (Labelled C) and S if they bigger` Again which number are you comparing here? Also, it would be helpful if you explain your output further with an example.

Comment: When I talk about `even number` I'm reffering to the 2, 4, 6,8 numbers in the plot column. Plots are labelled as `N` in the `Ori` column if they are smaller (plot 2 and 4 in this case) than the number which is median (`plot 5`, labelled as `C` in the ori column for `LE1`). Other plots (6 and 8) have higher numbers than the median, so they are labelled `S`.